# copy paste from one file to several files

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to copy some cells from one file to several files. In order to do so,the macro will copy the range and open the several files in order to paste the values. I perform a loop in order to open each of the destination files (the begin of the name of each of the ouput file is the same but the extension differs from file to file : it is based on a range of cells called Name). The concatenation doesn't work well.
Thank you so much for your help!!

```
Sub update()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wkbkorigin As Workbook
    Dim wkbkdestination As Workbook
    Dim originsheet As Worksheet
    Dim destsheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim nrow As Integer
    Dim ncol As Integer
    Dim Pathref As String
    Dim Name As String

   nrow = Range("names").Rows.Count
   ncol = Range("Range").Columns.Count

'this is the path to the different files, the begin is the same but the extension will be added in the loop (the extentsion is based on the value in the range Name

   Pathref = Range("Pathref").Value & "[yasmine_nouri]"

For i = 1 To nrow

    Name = Range("Names").Cells(i, 1).Value

    Set wkbkorigin = ActiveWorkbook
'here i set my destination file, the begin is the same but the extension is based on the value in the range Name : this concatenation doesn't work.

    Set wkbkdestination = Workbooks.Open([& Pathref & Name & ".xlsb"])

    Set originsheet = wkbkorigin.Worksheets("Completed_DS")
    Set destsheet = wkbkdestination.Worksheets("sheet1")

    originsheet.Range("D4:Q5").Copy
    destsheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    wkbkdestination.Close SaveChanges:=True

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: what is in your `Name` variable : `Name = Range("Names").Cells(i, 1).Value` ? extension like `.xlsm`?

Comment: My name variable is actually a row with names, for examples : apple,peer,oranges... My output file would be : yasmine_nouri_apple.xlsb, yasmine_nouri_peer.xlsb

Comment: and pathref is actually the link to the folder were all these output files are stocked : PATHREF = s:/folder/ and thus the final concatenation should give : s:/folder/yasmine_nouri_peer.xlsb

Comment: at first try to change `Set wkbkdestination = Workbooks.Open([& Pathref & Name & ".xlsb"])` to `Set wkbkdestination = Workbooks.Open(Pathref & Name & ".xlsb")`; at second, `My name variable is actually a row with names`, but you iterates throught column in line `Name = Range("Names").Cells(i, 1).Value`. If your names are in row, try to use `Name = Range("Names").Cells(1, i).Value` instead

Comment: O sorry Names is actually a column. Thanks so much, I will try this and come back with feedback!

Comment: btw, have you changed also `Pathref = Range("Pathref").Value & "[yasmine_nouri]"` to `Pathref = Range("Pathref").Value & "yasmine_nouri"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As follows up from comments, OP should change

```
Pathref = Range("Pathref").Value & "[yasmine_nouri]"
'...
Set wkbkdestination = Workbooks.Open([& Pathref & Name & ".xlsb"])
```

to

```
Pathref = Range("Pathref").Value & "yasmine_nouri"
'...
Set wkbkdestination = Workbooks.Open(Pathref & Name & ".xlsb")
```